# environments for objects whose relations are described by DOM

Tags: dom

Which are the environments for developing objects into PC memory? (The relations between the objects can be described by DOM(Document Object Model)  of any kind)

Comment: what does dom (document object model? dear old mothballs? there's way too many TLAs) have to do with pc memory?

Comment: sorry it's document object model, I edited the question.